# Android fragment using Achartengine - Chart disappears after switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine, lifecycle

I have an Android Fragment with an Achartengine line chart (copied from the official example from achartengine). My activity shows one fragment at a time and uses a menu to switch between those fragments. Showing the ChartFragment the first time works fine, but when I switch to another fragment and then switch back to my ChartFragment the chartview is gone.

```
public class MainActivity {

    // ...

    public void replaceFragment(int position) {
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                fragments.valueAt(position));
        fragTransaction.commit();
    }

    // ...
}

public class ChartFragment extends Fragment {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        View view = this.getView();

        if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                    mRenderer);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        } else {
                    mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }       

    // ...
}
```

The first call of `onResume()` works fine and the chart is created and displayed. If `onResume()` is called again the chart disappears. Calling `repaint()` doesn't help (mChartView is not null). How can I display the chart after switching back to this fragment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in place of ur replaceFragment()

```
 public void replaceFragment(int position) {
     FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = mFragmentManager
             .beginTransaction();
     fragTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragments.get(position));
     fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
 }
```

and onresume()

```
public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("onResume called");
        View view = this.getView();
        if(mChartView == null)
        {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), mDataset, mRenderer);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
        else
        {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }
```